# lauch AlertDialog from view inside another Activity

Tags: android, android-intent

My little game starts in an IntroActivity where user selects the level to play in an AlertDialog. This starts an Intent which opens the GameActivity which holds a View, where the game really happens. Inside, when the game is over, A new AlertDialog asks to play a new game. How can I launch the IntroActivity-AlertDialog from there, to start a new game? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i dont actually see how you have implemented your alert dialog, but from your code we can see that you need to use it twice ...

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity{

    public void createDialogToChooseLevel(){
        //implemenation
    }
}
```

and then you need to set

```
public class IntroActivity extends MyActivity{
  // you can call createDialogToChooseLevel here
}


public class GameActivity extends MyActivity{
  // you can call createDialogToChooseLevel here
}
```